# Как ждать ответ от пользователя и проверять его? Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Пользователь выбирает на клавиатуре категорию, *предупреждающие*, далее бот ему выводит картинку и должен ждать ответ от пользователя, сравнивать его с правильным ответом из БД и выводить сообщение верно или неверно. Знаю про FSM, но не понимаю как его тут применить.

```
async def text(message):
    if message.text == 'Предупреждающие':
        cur.execute("SELECT name, pic, description FROM signs WHERE category = '1'")
        finds = cur.fetchall()
        name, pic, description = random.choice(finds)
        text = f'{pic}'
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, InputFile(text))
        text1 = 'Верно, это правило' + f'{name} /n {description}'
        text2 = 'Неверно! Правильный ответ:' + f'{name} /n {description}'
        if message.text == f'{name}':
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text2)
```